# Google pagespeed insights V5 - Minimise Critical Request Depth

Tags: java, google-api-php-client, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I  analysed a web page URL  with [google PageSpeed insights tool.](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
I have a question regarding the audit rule "[Minimise Critical Request Depth](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/critical-request-chains?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown)" which shows what resources are loaded with a high priority in a web page.
Below are the metrics data displaying in this audit rule.
1) URL (Resource URL ).
2)  ms (?)
3)  KB (Kibibyte).
[Minimise Critical Request Depth Audit Rule- Google PSI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhjLR.png)
[What is "ms" unit in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4cL.png)

"request": {
                    "url": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/11-GHD2FVCL.css?AUIClients/RetailSearchAutocompleteAssets",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 1927422.779343,
                    "endTime": 1927422.779348,
                    "startTime": 1927422.76813,
                    "transferSize": 1864
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRK2P.png)
I'll accessing the same information using the [google page speed insights api](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed).

I have a couple of questions

1. What does the unit "ms" stand? (displaying in google pagespeed insights tool)
2. What does startTime, endTime and responseReceivedTime keys in API response data mean?
3. How to calculate /  which metric should be considered to map and get "ms" data from API (same as the way google pagespeed insights tool diplays it)?

Answer (score 0):

1) **ms** = milliseconds (1/1000 of a second).

---

2) **startTime** = when the request for a resource was made.

**responseReceivedTime** = when the server actually sent a response to the request.

**endTime** = when the request was fully received (everything downloaded)

---

3) To get this subtract the **startTime** from the **endTime** and multiply by 1000 to get ms.

i.e.

```
 (1927422.779348 - 1927422.76813) * 1000 = 11.2ms

 (endTime        - startTime    ) * 1000 = timeTaken in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you Graham Ritichie for quick help your answer helped me solve to issue, i tried with and tested different values most of them reached approximately using the formula